# statements about summation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

Could you help me prove this statements about summation?

[image]

I know that the second prove is easy of be written, but can I put that summation before cos(theta) and sin(theta)? yes. But why?

Do you know how can I put explicitly that sumation of cossine and sine according the first and the second members. I were thinking it, because I'd calcule the area of a sine function in a given distance...

Thank you.

Comment: It is a general fact, not too hard to prove,  that if $\sum_1^\infty (a_k+ib_k)$ converges (exists), then $\sum_1^\infty a_k$ and $\sum_1^\infty b_k$ both converge, and $\sum_1^\infty (a_k+ib_k)=\sum_1^\infty a_k +i\sum_1^\infty b_k$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, I don't see any infinite series in the question.

Comment: I assumed that OP saw that one needed $\sum_1^\infty (\cos(k\theta)+i\sin(k\theta))$, and worried about separating into two sums. But the wording is definitely not clear enough for this to be anything more than speculation.